# Addon domain and .htaccess file redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, addon-domain

I have two domains:

1. `maindomain.com`
2. `www.addondomain.com`

A `.htaccess` file in `maindomain.com` has this redirect

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([a-z0-9_]+\.)?maindomain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

It redirects www to non www version.

Another `.htaccess` file in `addondomain.com` have these redirect

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^addondomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.addondomain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^addondomain\.maindomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.addondomain\.maindomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.addondomain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.maindomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.addondomain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

All pages redirect well, but when I put another `.htaccess` file in a subdirectory, the redirect does not work. So, I write these rules in `image` subdirectory.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^addondomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.addondomain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^addondomain\.maindomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.addondomain\.maindomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.addondomain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.maindomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.addondomain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Now when I try to access `addondomain.maindomain.com/image/1.png` it redirects to `addondomain.maindomain.com/1.png` with a 404 error. Some how, the `image` directory is lost. I need another `.htaccess` file in subdirectory.

**UPDATE#1:** `addondomain` is subdomain of `maindomain` also, directory structure is:

```
/public_html
    .htaccess
    home.php (page of main domain)
    /addondomain.com (directory)
        home.php (page of addondomain)
        .htaccess
        /image (directory)
            .htaccess
            1.png
```

**UPDATE#2:**

This works if I set `.htaccess` like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.addondomain.com/image/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^addondomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.addondomain.com/image/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^addondomain\.maindomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.addondomain\.maindomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.addondomain.com/image/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Is there any way to using some code (I am bit new) in place of image like

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.addondomain.com/.*$/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Can you include your directory structure please. Is your `addondomain.com` pointing to a subdirectory of the `maindomain.com` document root? `.htaccess` files are inherited along the filesystem path, however, mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default. It is generally preferable to avoid multiple `.htaccess` files in subdirectories.

Comment: "Some how, image folder cut off." - Your rules in the image subdirectory don't include the "image" folder in the substitution, so that would be why the image folder is being "cut off". It would be easier (in `.htaccess`) to make use of the directory-prefix, rather than explicitly specifying absolute URLs.

Comment: " It would be easier (in .htaccess) to make use of the directory-prefix, rather than explicitly specifying absolute URLs" How to use directory-prefix, can you add some code

Comment: Why do you need to put another `.htaccess` in a subdirectory of the `addondomain.com`? Presumably you are doing more than domain canonicalisation? Do you need to redirect everything? For instance, personally, I would simply 403 all requests for `maindomain.com/addondomain.com/`. Do you have other subdomains that you need to account for?

Comment: (Sorry, my comment about the directory-prefix doesn't apply here, since you are canonicalizing the domain.)

Answer (score 0):

Whilst `.htaccess` files (in general) are "inherited" along the filesystem path, mod_rewrite directives are not (by default). mod_rewrite directives in a `.htaccess` file in a subdirectory will completely override those in the parent directory. This is why you are having to duplicate directives across multiple `.htaccess` files.

However, you can "inherit" the parent directives with the `RewriteOptions` directive in the `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory. For example:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
```

This results in the mod_rewrite directives from the parent directory being "copied" into the current `.htaccess` file. This might help your current situation, however, relying too much on mod_rewrite inheritance is generally a bad idea as it can result in unexpected results that can be hard to debug. Note that directives are literally "copied", so you can find that `RewriteRule` *patterns* that might work in the parent directory, no longer match in the subdirectory - so it's not a magic fix. Also, having multiple `.htaccess` files along the filesystem path can make the system hard to manage. Better to have just one `.htaccess` file in the root directory.

You've not stated *why* you need an additional `.htaccess` file in the `/images` subdirectory. For domain canonicalisation (which is all that your directives are doing) it's certainly not required. Ideally you should include the necessary directives in the parent `.htaccess` file.

Personally, I would simply block (ie. 403 Forbidden) all requests via the `maindomain.com`. This simplifies the `addondomain.com/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Block all access via maindomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.maindomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

# Canonicalise www.addondomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =addondomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Any additional rewrites relating to the /image subdirectory (for example)
#RewriteRule ^image/(.+) /get-image.php?file=$1 [L]
```

Another way to avoid the `maindomain.com` from interfering with the `addondomain.com` is to create the directory (that the subdomain and `addondomain.com` point to) outside of the `maindomain.com` directory tree. For example:

```
/public_html
    .htaccess
    home.php (page of main domain)
/addondomain.com (directory)
    home.php (page of addondomain)
    .htaccess
    /image (directory)
        1.png
```

Comment: The above shouldn't be triggering a 403 when accessing via `addondomain.com`? (The `RewriteOptions` directive was just an example, I would not recommend using that in your current config - it shouldn't be necessary. But you've not explained what exactly you are doing with this setup? Are you _only_ canonicalising the domain?)